# Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на другие пункты меню border у smokes исчезал?

Tags: css, html5

[image: меню]

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на другие пункты меню border у smokes  исчезал?
Есть код:

```css
.header_content a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #5EBCDF;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 10px;
 transition-duration: .3s;
}
.header_content_home:hover {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #FFDD00;
 color: #FFDD00;
}
.header_content_flash:hover {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #ffffff;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.header_content_smoke:hover {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #B2B2B2;
 color: #B2B2B2;
}
.header_content_molotov:hover {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #E75407;
 color: #E75407; 
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header_content">
   <a class="header_content_home loh" href="index.html">home</a>
   <a class="header_content_flash" href="flash.html">flash</a>
   <a class="header_content_smoke" href="smoke.html">smokes</a>
   <a class="header_content_molotov" href="molotov.html">molotov</a>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: js  в помощь. одного css не хватит тут

Comment: ты случаем не знаешь как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример как сделать это без JS. Отключаем `pointer-events` у родителя, но оставляем их у дочерних элементов:

```css
body {
  background: #10202d;
}

.header_content {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.header_content a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #5EBCDF;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.header_content_home:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #FFDD00;
  color: #FFDD00;
}

.header_content_flash:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header_content_smoke:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #B2B2B2;
  color: #B2B2B2;
}

.header_content_molotov:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #E75407;
  color: #E75407;
}

.active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #B2B2B2;
}

.header_content:hover a.active:not(:hover) {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header_content">
    <a class="header_content_home" href="index.html">home</a>
    <a class="header_content_flash" href="flash.html">flash</a>
    <a class="header_content_smoke active" href="smoke.html">smokes</a>
    <a class="header_content_molotov" href="molotov.html">molotov</a>
  </div>
</header>
```